# What does the "0-cloud" mirror stands for in R?

Tags: r, cran

What does `0-cloud` mirror stands for in R 3.x.x ? Just after installation R 3.0.1 I spotted that there is new mirror called "0-cloud" what is it ? I can't google it, I suppose that appeared just in 3.0.1 version.

Comment: Choose local, that's all I got. Not sure why this R-studio meta-mirror  exists since it really doesn't seem to work, maybe it's ok in the U.S.

Comment: @mdsumner it should work just fine wherever in the world you are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a [content-delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDN) created by [RStudio](http://rstudio.com) to provide "local" CRAN mirrors.  CDNs essentially bring mirroring to "the edge of your network".  Think Akamai hosted by or near your particular ISP. The Wikipedia article I linked to has more.

I always presumed the name was mostly chosen to sort highest...

Comment: FWIW we didn't choose the name - it was assigned to us by CRAN.

Comment: Doesn't take away from the 'sorting highest' motivation, does it?