# install.packages() enforce no CRAN mirror selection?

Tags: r

When running `install.packages("somepackage")` from terminal, the pop out gui to select a CRAN mirror can be inconvenient and somewhat unnecessary.

Is there a way to call `install.packages("somepackage")` (from R in the terminal) so as to avoid having to select a mirror via the gui, but doesn't require [naming a specific mirror address/mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488224/5783745)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but what you want is using ``install.packages()`` without naming a mirror so R is choosing the appropriate mirror itself?

Comment: @Gainz yes perfect

Comment: @Gainz There is no such thing as "the appropriate mirror". The choice is arbitrary and ideally results in load balancing.

Comment: @Roland I mean in Canada R will most likely not use the Taiwan mirror of the Cran.

Comment: @Roland *any* mirror is good. I usually select one geographically close to me, but to save 0.5 seconds (through faster download speed), it's hardly worth messing around outside the terminal and reading the sentence asking for selection

Comment: @user5783745 Try using the following url : ``https://cloud.r-project.org``.

Comment: Like this : ``install.packages("names", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")`` from what I read it should give you a mirror that is close to you most of the timeé

Comment: Don't use CRAN without mirror. Use the first mirror in the list, [RStudio's 0Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875174/what-does-the-0-cloud-mirror-stands-for-in-r).

Comment: @Gainz we could put any mirror's url in the `repos` option but ideally I would like to not to have to know a CRAN mirror off the top of my head

Comment: @Roland is there any way to select the first without the gui opening and selecting, as in, using code (and conveniently). E.g. something like `install.packages("names", repos = NULL)` (<- that doesn't work, just an example of what would be nice)

Comment: @user5783745 The url I gived you gives a mirror that is close to you (or at least one that is always going to be near).

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488727/10447055

Comment: @Gainz ah I see. That's helpful. Any way to do that without having to remember a url? `repos = 'chooseforme' would be handy

Comment: @Gainz I thought `install.packages("names", repos = chooseCRANmirror())` would do as desired, but even it requires (manual) selection from a list it presents

Comment: you could randomly choose a CRAN mirror like this `install.packages("names", repos = sample(getCRANmirrors()$URL, 1))`

Comment: @user5783745 Yes because that function return a list of the available mirrors. Can I know why you can't just add manually the name of the cloud mirror or select 1 when using ``chooseCRANmirrors()``?

Comment: @Gainz, to be honest, because I won't remember it when I need it

Comment: @Gainz not that `install.packages("names", repos = getCRANmirrors()$URL[1])` is much more memorable

Comment: @user5783745 Yes it is the same thing! I simply wanted to put the repos's link but you could use this without any problem.

Comment: @Gainz I was hoping for something shorter and more easily remembered than both `install.packages("names", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")` and `install.packages("names", repos = getCRANmirrors()$URL[1])`. ideally something like `install.packages("names", repos ="best")`, but it sounds this is not possible so your solution and a slightly simpler version of Tom's are best

Comment: @user5783745 See my answer, thats the only way I know of setting it "automatically" but you will need to modify your ``.Rprofile`` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
install.packages("names", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

You could also set the mirror you want with :

`options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="getCRANmirrors()$URL[1]")))`

in a `.Rprofile` file so your R will automatically use this repos when you will call :

`install.packages()`.